# Reflux how to listen for async action completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

From reading the docs I don't quite understand how Reflux async actions work. In particular I need to trigger something when an async action completes.

In one of my components I want to listen for an async action complete and then transition to a view.

```
mixins: [State, Navigation, Reflux.listenerMixin],

componentDidMount() {
  this.listenTo(actions.loadProject.completed, ()=>{this.transitionTo('info')});
},
```

I have created my action like this:

```
var actions = Reflux.createActions([
  "someSyncAction",
  "anotherSyncAction"
]);

actions.loadProject = Reflux.createAction({
  "loadProject": {children: ['completed','failed']},
});
```

And in my projectStore I have something like this:

```
 onLoadProject(id) {

    var url = '/api/projects/' + id;
    io.socket.get(url, (body, jwr) => {

      if(jwr.statusCode !== 200){
        console.error('Failed to load project', id, body);
        return actions.loadProject.failed();
      }

      var p = body;
      debug('loaded project', id, p);
      this.project = p;
      this.trigger(p);
      actions.loadProject.completed();
    });
  },
```

But it appears actions.loadProject.completed is not a function, so the above code won't work. What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that my original code didn't work because of one typo and one mistake. Below are the corrections.

```
mixins: [State, Navigation, Reflux.listenerMixin],
```

Should have been

```
mixins: [State, Navigation, Reflux.ListenerMixin],
```

I believe warnings for undefined mixins have been added to React, but apparently didn't make it into my version yet.

```
actions.loadProject = Reflux.createAction({
 "loadProject": {children: ['completed','failed']},
});
```

Should have been

```
actions.loadProject = Reflux.createAction({children: ['completed','failed']});
```

I had used the syntax from createAction**s** instead. That's why loadProject.completed wasn't a function. Reflux created a plain action without complaining apparently.

In Tim Arney's example shows that you can keep the API call in a separate action listener and have the store only listen for the completed action. I think I prefer to keep the API call with the store logic. If anyone thinks there's a good reason not to I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: I've read multiple posts and discussions regarding where to put the API calls. Based on these discussions I tend to favour a 'get' call in the action creator (using preEmit) and a post / put call in the store. The first keeps your stores clean and the latter makes it easier to respond to different outcomes of the calls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Reflux myself, here's a demo I put together.  Not sure if it's 100% proper but might help you - http://jsbin.com/roqito/2/edit

Comment: Thanks @Tim Arney, from your code I was able to figure out what was wrong with mine. Turned out I wasn't far off at all...

Comment: There is some info here you might find useful
https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/issues/194 && http://spoike.ghost.io/refluxjs-0-1-8/

Some talk about using preEmit

`ProductActions.load.preEmit = function () {  
     // Perform the API call
};`

Comment: Thanks for the links! Useful info. I wish there was more from the 0.1.8 writeup in the docs.

Comment: It is very easy to read example. I knew something beforehand about Reflux, but with this example it was so easy to start actually using it.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflux#asynchronous-actions-as-promises):

```
// Create async action with `completed` & `failed` children 
var makeRequest = Reflux.createAction({ asyncResult: true });
```